Garage Insulation in Houston
I have a 25x25 foot detached garage in Houston, TX. It's very hot/humid here. I'm considering insulating and putting in a mini-split. Its a pyramid hip and has no venting. It has tar paper between the studs and the wood siding. The tar paper is old and has scattered holes.
After some research I think I have decided to use closed cell foam on the roof deck. I still haven't figured out the walls. I don't want to remove the siding. I was hoping to just place something in stud cavities. From what I have read I need a Class II vapor barrier that needs to be facing towards the exterior. Without removing siding that would make it difficult to create a continuous barrier.
I was thinking I could use some XPS fitted to cavities and some foam or tape to seal it, then cover that with unfaced fiberglass insulation. I don't want to use the closed cell foam because of electrical wiring. Any advice? Is there a more economical approach?

You've described your situation well, but you haven't asked a clear question. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Also, what does "because of electrical wiring" mean? Conduit is a fairly cheap remedy if you have future wiring planned.

Sorry.  My main question is: what would the best way to insulate the walls be?   With the considerations that I need to put vapor barrier out facing rather than in and cant remove siding to do that correctly.  seeing if anyone has ideas for a work around.
For the electrical wiring I was just concerned that spray foam would encase/cover the wiring and make it difficult to work on in the future if needed.  but im not experienced so could be wrong
thanks

Don't put it down here. Revise your question.
